# whats new in .net 4.0 for webparts

Tags: .net, web-parts

I have to decide whether to use .net 3.5 or 4.0 for a webportal, I have found that webparts cannot be moved accross the webpartzone also there is problem with verbs.

What is new in .net 4.0 for webparts and which is better 3.5 or 4.0 ?

Comment: Do you have any webpart Sharepoint plans?

Comment: yes I would love to see them working in sharepoint.

Comment: still wondering if there is something new in the framework, like design mode support in firefox and etc